# add comma before certain character

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have this CSV file:

```
"ADFS-Administrators","Administrator-Access","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/companyADFS"
"ADFS-amtest-ro","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/companyADFS"
"AWSAccCorpAdmin","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/LastPass"
"AWScompanyCorpAdmin","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/LastPass"
"AWScompanyCorpPowerUser","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/LastPass"
"flowlogsRole","oneClick_flowlogsRole_1495032428381",
"companyDevShutdownEC2Instaces","oneClick_lambda_basic_execution_1516271285849",
"companySAMLUser","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/companyAzureAD"
"lambda_stop_rundeck_instance","oneClick_lambda_basic_execution_1519651160794",
"OneLoginAdmin","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/OneLoginAdmin"
"OneLoginDev","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/OneLoginDev"
"vmimport","vmimport",
"workspaces_DefaultRole","SkyLightServiceAccess",
```

I want to add another comma in each line if after the first comma there is a string which starts with `arn:aws:iam:`

Desired output (partial):

```
"ADFS-amtest-ro",,"arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/companyADFS"
"AWSAccCorpAdmin",,"arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/LastPass"
"AWScompanyCorpAdmin",,"arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/LastPass"
"AWScompanyCorpPowerUser",,"arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/LastPass
```

For lines which doesn't have the string which starts with `arn:aws:iam`, don't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*\)\(,"arn:aws:iam:\)/\1,\2/'
```

Answer (score 2):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }$2 ~ /^"arn:aws:iam:/{ $2 = ","$2 }1' file.csv
```

- `$2 ~ /^"arn:aws:iam:/` - if the 2nd field `$2` starts with `"arn:aws:iam:`
- `$2 = ","$2` - prepend the 2nd field value with `,`

---

The output:

```
"ADFS-Administrators","Administrator-Access","arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/companyADFS"
"ADFS-amtest-ro",,"arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/companyADFS"
"AWSAccCorpAdmin",,"arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/LastPass"
"AWScompanyCorpAdmin",,"arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/LastPass"
"AWScompanyCorpPowerUser",,"arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/LastPass"
"flowlogsRole","oneClick_flowlogsRole_1495032428381",
"companyDevShutdownEC2Instaces","oneClick_lambda_basic_execution_1516271285849",
"companySAMLUser",,"arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/companyAzureAD"
"lambda_stop_rundeck_instance","oneClick_lambda_basic_execution_1519651160794",
"OneLoginAdmin",,"arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/OneLoginAdmin"
"OneLoginDev",,"arn:aws:iam::279052847476:saml-provider/OneLoginDev"
"vmimport","vmimport",
"workspaces_DefaultRole","SkyLightServiceAccess",
```

Comment: As always, perfect answer, i'm in dept to you Roman !